# Why has Google Maps' "globe view" suddenly stopped working in NW.js, but not Vivaldi?

Tags: windows, windows-10, chromium, google-maps

I use NW.js (Chromium) to make a desktop map application for my own use.

I have given it a feature which on request opens a new window of itself (Chromium) with Google Maps at the specified coordinates.

Until a couple of weeks or so ago, there were no problems. But now, the "globe view" feature (which is crucial) is simply "greyed out"/disabled, as if I were running a browser from 1994 or something.

But I'm literally using Google's own engine, *and* I made sure to re-build it yesterday with the latest version of NW.js (meaning latest version of Chromium).

How is it possible that the "globe view" is disabled in spite of using their latest browser engine? It just doesn't make sense.

Online, there are about six trillion search results about this, but all of them are years old and completely unrelated to NW.js.

Interestingly, the "glove view" feature **is** available when I just looked at Google Maps in Vivaldi (on the same computer), which is a browser that is *also* using Chromium...

PS: Github doesn't allow registration of accounts, so I'm unable to "file an issue" at NW.js' repo there.